# How can I plot functions with varying parameters in one plot?

Tags: r, plot

Good evening,

I have a function f with the arguments a, x and y. For different values of y I would like to plot this function into a diagram with a different colour for each value of y. I defined a list of colours to be used and tried to use the function expand.grid for setting the different values of y, however I only get one strange line plotted in red.

The code looks as follows:

```
library (ggplot2)

colors <- c ("red", "violet", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "orange")


#function
f <- function(a,x,y){
  -(1/a)*y*x
}

expand.grid(y = c (0.1,0.2,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.5))


#plot it for different y
plot (f(1,1:1000,y), type="l", col = colors, xlab = "x", ylab = "f")
```

The plot,
[image]
It would be great if somebody could help me. I just started out in coding (and this is my first stackoverflow-post, I'm sorry for possible inconveniences)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the smartest solution, but it could get you there.

```
   plot(f(1,1:1000,y[1]), col=colors[1], type="l")
  lines(f(1,1:1000,y[2]), col=colors[2])
  lines(f(1,1:1000,y[3]), col=colors[3])
  lines(f(1,1:1000,y[4]), col=colors[4])
  lines(f(1,1:1000,y[5]), col=colors[5])
  lines(f(1,1:1000,y[6]), col=colors[6])
  lines(f(1,1:1000,y[7]), col=colors[7])
```

[image: a start, plot]
if you want to use [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) you take a look at [these examples](https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/ggplot2-stat-function).

Comment: Hey this helped a lot, thank you so much!